# cv2.imwrite Mangles TIFF Output

Tags: python, opencv

I've been playing with OpenCV 3.1.0 in Python. My code works great, but when it comes time to write it out to a TIFF file, this happens:

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]

My code to reproduce this is literally two lines:

```
f = cv2.imread('f.tif', 0)
cv2.imwrite('test.tif', f)
```

Both `f.tif` and the resulting `test.tif` are 8-bit greyscale TIFF files, according to ImageMagick.

Writing the image to PNG instead of TIFF works just fine.

Comment: Stop complaining - that's nice and sharp ;-) ;-)

Comment: It is working fine on my machine (Linux, OpenCV2.x) :)

Comment: I also can't reproduce this. Might be time to rebuild libTIFF and openCV.

Comment: Can you post the TIFF itself? Also what versions of OpenCV etc.